# How to prove that $Arccos z = -i Ln (z + \sqrt{z^2 - 1})$

Tags: complex-analysis

Noting the definition of $Arc cos z \iff z = \cos z \ \ z = \frac{1}{2i}(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})$
The next step would be $z 2i = e^{iw} + e^{-iw}$, but I don't understand why. Then after that the equation is multiplied by $e^{iw} $ and we get $(e^{iw })^2 - 2z i e^{iw } +1$ . Again I don't understand this step, can someone enlighten me about this proof and what's done here?

Comment: In order to invert $\cos{(w)}$ to obtain $w$ the equation is treated as a quadratic in $e^{iw}$ where $z$ is constant

Comment: @PeterForeman I don't understand how we get to this quadratic form.

Comment: I don't know what to say. You have shown every step required to obtain the quadratic form$$x^2-2izx+1=0$$where $x=e^{iw}$ is the variable of interest.

Comment: Surely $cos z=\frac{1}{2}(e^{iw}+e^{-iw})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$$
w = \arccos z
$$
then
$$
z = \cos w.
$$
Write the cosine function in terms of the exponential function:
$$
z = \frac{1}{{2}}(e^{iw}  + e^{ - iw} ).
$$
Multiply both sides by $2$:
$$
2z = e^{iw}  + e^{ - iw} .
$$
Multiply both sides by $e^{iw}$:
$$
2ze^{iw}  = e^{iw} (e^{iw}  + e^{ - iw} ) = e^{2iw}  + 1.
$$
Re-arrange:
$$
e^{2iw}  - 2ze^{iw}  + 1 = 0.
$$
Set $x = e^{iw}$, then it is a quadratic equation in $x$:
$$
x^2  - 2zx + 1 = 0.
$$
One can solve it by using the quadratic formula to obtain
$$
x = z \pm \sqrt {z^2  - 1}  \Rightarrow iw = \log (z \pm \sqrt {z^2  - 1} ) \Rightarrow w =  - i\log (z \pm \sqrt {z^2  - 1} ).
$$
To obtain the principal branch of $\arccos$, one has to choose the sign $+$.

Answer (score 0):

Basically start of by using the formula $cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}=\theta$ we just call cos(x) θ for comfort, we know that arccos(θ)=x thus if we find x in θ, we get the formula for the arccos, so our goal is it to solve for x in θ, we can let $e^{ix}=y$ And get $\theta =\frac{y+y^{-1}}{2}$ multiplying by 2y we get $2y\theta =y^2+1$ which we can easily solve as it is a quadratic equations.